# Python API design for existing Java API

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, closures

I am new to python and I have to design a Python API(version - 2.7) similar to an existing Java API

**Python version - 2.7**

The Java API is as follows

```
public interface Process<T> {

  Future<T> create(Client<T> client)

  //Other methods
}

public interface Client<T> extends Serializable {

  T execute(ClientContext c)

  //Other methods
}

public interface ClientContext {

  File createFile(String path)

  //Other methods
}
```

The equivalent Python API design that I have come up with is

**Approach1**

```
class Process:
  __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

@abstractmethod
def create(self, client):
    pass

class Client:
  __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

@abstractmethod
def execute(self, context):
    pass

class ClientContext:
  __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

@abstractmethod
def createFile(self, path):
    pass
```

**Approach2**

Can I use closures to directly pass the context to the create function of Process class so that I can eliminate the Client class

**Note** The create method of Process class will process async tasks which can be done using concurrent.futures package from python.

I want to know which of the 2 approaches is good

Also open to better approaches as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would use closure to create function templates , like the case where i want to generate many functions of the same template with different variables

example

```
def add(x):
    def addto(y):
        return x+y
    return addto

addto5 = add(5)
print addto5(1)
#will print 6
```

In your case closure does not look a good alternative as in closure you can only change the variables but the function procedure (template) is constant while in normal class with inheritance it will give you much more freedom

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you tell how I can pass the context directly to the create function of Process class

Comment: that would be simple just create client object and pass it directly to process like this create(Client().execute(context))

Comment: Client is an abstract class here

Comment: the only way i know is the ugly way using type method  like this
type("ClientImpl", (Client, object), {"execute": lambda self,context : context})().execute(None)

Comment: The type method here created subclass on the fly from client and overridden the execute function there. then i just called it with none to make sure the code works

Comment: no. The implementation class fro ClientImpl will be chosen at run-time. The caller does not have access to that

Comment: if there is an  The implementation class for Client the end user will just create Client object from it like Client client = createClient(). then we will set the context on client and use the client object to pass it to the create method. Not sure if i get the question correctly here